# Excel column value with big spaces in between

Tags: excel, formula

In the excel, i have a content exactly looks like the one below. i need to use excel formula remove all the unnecessary info. Only keep the -.pdf.

> 1-Abc.pdf is a pdf containing important stuff
>
> 2-Def.pdf is a pdf containing important stuff
>
> 3-Ghi.pdf is a pdf containing important stuff
>
> 4-Jkl.pdf is a pdf containing important stuff

my final result like this below.

`1-Abc.pdf`
`2-Def.pdf`
`3-Ghi.pdf`
`4-Jkl.pdf`

Please help. I have uploaded a sample below.
http://www.4shared.com/file/w_BSr62W/Sample.html?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your other question that was closed. There were several suggestions before the question was closed. Is the data you post as the "Before" all in one cell? Because you rejected suggestions that worked perfectly fine for the data in different cells. You may need to provide a bit more information about your source data. A sample spreadsheet would certainly help. Use one of the many free file storage sites.

Comment: Please don't just ask the same question again and again. Improve your first question so it can get reopened. If you carry on like this you are likely to hit the automatic question ban.

Comment: Since my first question is marked as [Closed], therefore i will create another question hence the question is similar but there is no actual solution.

Comment: @ArchdeaconBlue - ChrisF just gave you exact instructions as to what to do.  Improve your first question, and flag it for moderator attention to have it reopened.  Please do not create *another* question.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is below:

```
Sub TrimToFirstSpace()
    Dim strHolder As String
    Dim intSlicer As Integer

    strHolder = ActiveCell.Value
    intSlicer = InStr(1, strHolder, " ")

    strHolder = Left(strHolder, intSlicer - 1)
End Sub
```

You can put strHolder into the `Activecell.Value` or elsewhere, if you like.

Comment: Can this be used in excel? I need a formula in excel

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to automate the process. The formula is: =LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1) assuming your data is in column A

Comment: I only get the first line. '1-Abc.pdf'

Comment: The formula is only looking at one line, you'll need to copy that formula down a column in your data, or use the vba solution in a loop if you have lots of rows.